# Ps Vita Black Screenshots?

Tags: ps-vita

When i take screenshots on my Ps Vita (Ps Button + Start) they do not appear, or appear as black images, but this only seems to happen with games. 
Does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some Vita games and all PSP and PSX/PS1 don't allow you to take screenshots. For Vita games, this is usually chosen by the Developer or Publisher for unknown reasons. For PSP and PSX/PS1 games, this is by design of the emulators used for those systems.

This limitation can be removed on Vita consoles via Homebrew with a plugin called [pngshot](https://github.com/xyzz/pngshot). The plugin will not only remove the screenshot limitation but also remove any watermarks when applicable and store the images as PNG Files.

As an example, here is a screenshot of Hatsune Miku: Project Diva (the original PSP Game) taken directly from a PS Vita with pngshot:

[image]